# Delete Tuples in List

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

i want to delete Tuples out of a list if they have the same number...

```
list1 = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (25, 25), (0, 9), (26, 26), (27, 27)]
```

and I need

```
list2 = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 9)]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what have you tried? you have not show any attempt at the problem. This isnt a homework completing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list2 = [item for item in list1 if item[0] != item[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's enough to write the code that I wrote a note

[image]

Comment: Don't screenshot code into stack overflow